# Why do you have to do division in these trigonomic equations?

Tags: trigonometry

For example $\sin 2x= 1$,
the unit circle gives all these answers for $\sin x = 1 $:
$$
\frac{\pi}{2} + n 2 \pi,\quad  \text{(so n times 2pi as you can rotate endlessly)}
$$
but since there is 2x you have to divide 1/2pi by 2, thus 1/4pi, but why do you have to divide n*2pi by 2 as well?

The answer of the equation is apparently 1/4pi + n*pi

Can someone explain this (visually with the unit circle) why all the solutions of 1/4pi + n*2pi are wrong?

Also when you have sin x +1/3pi = 0

the solution is x= n*pi - 1/3pi

which is very clear from me as you have to balance the extra 1/3pi out, so you subtract 1/3pi from all the solutions.

(or compensate/cancel out, whatever english term fits best).

But when it comes to sin2x= y

I dont understand the balancing of division. Is there a way to explain why (preferably with the unit circle) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: any links to videos would be great as well

Comment: $(2n\pi + \pi/2)/2 = n\pi + \pi/4$

Comment: yes i know, but it doesnt explain why n2π+π/4 would be wrong set of solutions

Comment: "why do you have to divide 2*2pi by 2 as well?": there is no $2\cdot2\pi$.

Comment: Since $\pi + \pi/4$ is a valid solution which is not included in $2n\pi + \pi/4$, your solution  set does not contain all possible solutions.

Comment: It would indeed be a valid set of solutions, but it wouldn't contain all solutions.

Comment: Can we say that whenever there is a number in front of the x, so lets call it a. thus ax, the  number of solutions will be a, if they have to be within the domain of 0 and 2pi?

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution $\frac \pi4+n\pi$ covers
$$ \ldots,\frac\pi4-2\pi,\frac\pi4-\pi,\frac \pi4,\frac\pi4+\pi,\frac\pi4+2\pi,\frac\pi4+3\pi,\ldots$$
whereas $\frac \pi4+2n\pi$ covers (only)
$$ \ldots,\frac\pi4-2\pi,\frac \pi4,\frac\pi4+2\pi,\frac\pi4+4\pi,\ldots$$
So you found *some* solution (asyou would have if you had written $\frac\pi4$ only), but not *all*.

Comment: @player3236 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$\sin (2x) = 1 \\\Rightarrow 2x = \dfrac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi\\
\Rightarrow x = ?$

Answer (score 0):

The solutions of

$$\sin y=1$$ are $$y=\frac\pi2+2k\pi.$$

And if $y=2x$, mechanically

$$2x=\frac\pi2+2k\pi\iff x=\frac\pi4+k\pi.$$

This is elementary arithmetic.